# Add data from Textbox to DataGridView on button click in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

My Window has 2 `TextBox`,one `Button` and a `DataGridView`, when I click the button, the `DataGridView` need to display the values of `TextBox`

This is what I have until now:

```
private void btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("id");
    dt.Columns.Add("name");
    DataRow dr = null;

    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {    
         dr = dt.NewRow();
         dt.Rows.Add(txt1.Text, txt2.Text);
         grid1.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
    }
}
```

In this case `DataGrid`'s rows get updated, but not adding values one by one!

Is there a way to accomplish this in WPF?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to add the new Item (which could be anonymous) to the `Items` collection.

Eg;

```
   <DataGrid x:Name="Dgrd" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Binding="{Binding ID}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="NAME" Binding="{Binding NAME}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Code

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Dgrd.Items.Add(new { ID = IDTextbox.Text, NAME = NAMETextbox.Text });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

define the datagrid columns 
and bind the data onto that corresponding coloumns

```
<Grid>
    <TextBox x:Name="txt1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="44,32,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="txt2"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="204,32,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
    <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Margin="231,75,0,0" Click="Button_Click"/>
    <DataGrid x:Name="grid1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="44,138,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="139" Width="280">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Binding="{Binding ID}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="NAME" Binding="{Binding NAME}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>

</Grid>
```

code behind

```
  private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
         grid1.Items.Add(new { ID = txt1.Text, NAME = txt2.Text });
    }
```